# How to make the url of the web browser stay as it is in MVC error 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

My problem , I went to Microsoft.com and input https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/heywhatsupdude , 404 shows up which is correct, i have no problem with it ,THEN i noticed the url is still the same , i mean , I was expecting https://learn.microsoft.com/NotFound.cshtml but then its still https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/heywhatsupdude

So my question is, how to do this in MVC 5 or 4? Sawadika!!! hOW TO MAKE the url stay as what it is , what you input? huh?

Comment: Perhaps the `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` option is what you are looking for. Also, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.customerrorssection.redirectmode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Runtime error it says

Comment: When you return a View either from the action itself or from a custom exception filter, the url will not change for the user because they aren't hitting the web server again. If you were to return a Redirect to another action, that would cause the browser to call back to the web server and therefore change the url in the browser.